# How to find if a point is inside or outside the circle

Tags: c#, oop, geometry

I need to figure out if the point is inside or outside the circle. I already did a code that sees if it is on the circle.

**But I need help with this portion**

- I need to create 3 methods to find if it is:

onCircle (Point p),

inCircle (Point p),

outCircle (Point p)

(Basically I need to determine if a point p lies on circle c, inside circle, or outside the circle.)

To find if it is in the circle or out the circle do I just make a method that shows that the distance of p is greater than or less than the radius. For example:

```
    public bool onCircle(Point p)
    {
        return dist(p) > radius;
    }
```

Would it make sense? if I took the distance of x and y and compared it to the radius of the circle would it be correct?

Here is my code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Circle c1 = new Circle(0, 0, 1), c2 = new Circle(1, 0, 1);
    Point p1 = new Point();
    p1.setPoint(0, 1);

    p1.print();
    Console.Write(", ");
    c1.print();
    Console.WriteLine();
    if (c1.onCircle(p1))
    {
       // Console.Write(" Point ");
        p1.print();
        Console.Write (" on ");
        c1.print();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Point NOT on circle");

    if (c1.intersect(c2))
    {
       // Console.WriteLine("Two circles intersect");
        c1.print();
        Console.Write(" intersects ");
        c2.print();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    else

        Console.WriteLine("Two circles do NOT intersect");
}
```

My Class:

```
class Circle : Point
{
    private double radius;
    public Circle(double xV, double yV, double r)
    {
        this.x = xV;
        this.y = yV;
        this.radius = r;
    }
    public void setRadius(double r)
    {
        radius = r > 0 ? radius : 0;
    }

    public bool onCircle(Point p)
    {
        return dist(p) == radius;
    }

    public bool intersect (Circle c)
    {
        Point p = new Point (), myCenter = new Point();
        p.setPoint (c.x, c.y);
        myCenter.setPoint (x, y);

        return myCenter.dist(p) < radius + c.radius;
    }
    public void print()
    {
        Console.Write("Circle: ({0}, {1}, {2})", x, y, radius);
    }
}
```

Class for point:

```
public class Point
{
    protected double x; // x coordiate of Point
    protected double y; // y coordinate of Point

    public void setPoint (double xCoor, double yCoor) {
        x = xCoor;
        y = yCoor;
    }

    public double dist(Point p)  // compute the distance of point p to the current point
    {
        double distance;
        distance = Math.Sqrt((x - p.x) * (x - p.x) + (y - p.y) * (y - p.y));
        return distance;
    }
    public void print()
    {
        Console.Write("Point: ({0}, {1})", x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, in particular please create a minimal test case and ask a very specific question.

Comment: To say a point is "on" the circle, you may want to check that it is within a certain tolerance (i.e. not too far) from the true edge of the circle. A point e-14 away from the circle we'd probably all call "on the circle" but an equality test == will fail.

Comment: Calculate the length of the vector from the middle of the circle to the point you want to check. If the length is smaller than the radius of the circle the point is inside the circle.

Comment: why dont you test it your self? btw what i see seems correct but note that double is floating point and `dist(p) == radius` may not always give you the expected result.

Comment: I tested it but needed to make sure if I was going the right way with the math and my code.

Comment: use `Math.Abs(dist(p) - radius) < 0.0001`  instead of `dist(p) == radius`. so any point that is close to the radius (closer than `0.0001`) will be considered on circle.

Comment: `Math.Sqrt` is a slow operation. It will be more efficient to compare the squared distance with the squared radius. Instead of calling 3 separate methods to determine where a point is relative to a circle, write one method that returns a number that's either negative (inside the circle), zero (on the circle) or positive (outside the circle).

Comment: If you are testing a great many points, you should instead use a `distSquared()` method that doesn't take the square root, and then compare it with the square of the radius. This will be much faster.